# Why does round sometimes produce extra digits?

Tags: t-sql

Occasionally, when selecting aggregate data (usually `AVG()`) from a database, I'll get a repeating decimal such as:

```
2.7777777777777777
```

When I apply `ROUND(AVG(x), 2`) to the value, I sometimes get a result like:

```
2.7800000000000002
```

I happen to know that the actual sample has 18 rows with `SUM(x)` = 50.  So this command should be equivalent:

```
SELECT ROUND(50.0/18, 2)
```

However, it produces the expected result ([2.78](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179688)). Why does rounding sometimes produce wrong results with aggregate functions?

---

In order to verify the above result, I wrote a [query against a dummy table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179689/rounding-bug):

```
declare @temp table(
  x float
)

insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (2.0);
insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (1.0);
insert into @temp values (8.0);
insert into @temp values (9.0);

select round(avg(x), 2),
       sum(x),count(*)
from @temp
```

I'm aware of the [gotchas of floating point representation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), but this simple case seems not to be subject to those.

Comment: I've experienced this behaviour before but thought it was by-design..

Comment: "this simple case seems not to be subject to [gotchas of floating point representation]." A very fast way to find out is to use one of [IEEE 754 calculators](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). Enter the desired value, and check the resultant representation. For 2.78 you get `2.7799999713897705`.

Comment: It seems like too many zeroes in the value you got. Trying out the calculator that @dasblinkenlight linked, I see the binary value of 2.7799999713897705 is 01000000001100011110101110000101 (as a double). Incrementing to 01000000001100011110101110000110 yields a decimal value of 2.7800002. ?!?

Comment: Does that mean it's impossible to store any values between 2.7799999713897705 and 2.7800002? Surely there are binary representations for the intervals between. In which case, there should be a way to round more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

Decimal numbers don't always (or even usually) map 1:1 to an exact representation in floating point.

In your case, the two closest numbers that double precision floating point can represent are;

- [40063D70A3D70A3D](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=40063D70A3D70A3D) which is approximately 2.77999999999999980460074766597
- [40063D70A3D70A3E](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=40063D70A3D70A3E) which is approximately 2.78000000000000024868995751604

There exists no double precision number between those two numbers, in this case the database chose the higher value which - as you see - rounds to 2.7800000000000002.

Comment: That's a sensible explanation as far as it goes. However, this seems to be a implementation quirk since other SQL dialects do the expected thing: `sqlite3 t.db 'select round(cast(25.0/9.0 as double), 2);'` => 2.78

Answer (score 2):

Your table uses floats. When given floats as parameters, both `AVG()` and `ROUND()` return floats. Floats cannot be precisely represented. When you do `ROUND(50.0/18, 2)` you're giving it `NUMERIC(8,6)` which it returns as `DECIMAL(8,6)`.

Try declaring your columns to use a more precise type like `DECIMAL(18,9)`. The results should be more predictable.

Comment: You are certainly correct that the problem stems from the type of the argument to `ROUND()` (as can be observed in [this test](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179699)). However, I can't change the type of the column. I _was_ able to [work around the problem](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179706/rounding-bug-fixed) with `round(avg(cast(x as decimal)), 2)` in the query itself.