# C# Decimal conversion to float and insert into sql float column

Tags: c#, sql

I am having a hard time getting around this issue.

I am working with a enterprise DB table that has a column called `balance` which is a `float`.

I am trying to insert a `decimal` value into it. Now in c# I tried round the decimal to 2 places then inserting it into the column and it just does this.
`56.4000015258789` when my value is `56.40`.

I am debugging just before my insert and it is rounded. I can't change the column . . .so how do I get around this?

I know it has something to do with how sql considers fractions.

I tried formatting the decimal to a string then parsing it to a float and that didn't work.

Comment: `float` in C# only has 7 digits of precision, and can't represent all non-integer values exactly.  Try `double` instead.  If you need to keep the decimal representation in SQL use a `decimal` column instead

Comment: @DStanley I can't change the column, it really frustrating.

Comment: @AdamV The problem is that the float value before insertion is rounded off. But when It get inside sql for some reason starts making up training numbers.

Comment: If you can't change the column, then you are stuck with this behavior.   You will just have to round at query time if you only want to see 2 digits.

Comment: @TabAlleman The problem is the enterprise software running this will blow up if I don't round it. . . . . I have seen in the dev database version of this with rounded off floats. Granted they did this in access server 2003 with VB.

Comment: You can't change the software and you can't change the database?   Then what exactly are you working on?

Comment: You'd probably see the same thing if you cast your "rounded" `float` to a `double`.  The problem is that the _actual_ float value is very slightly different, but it doesn't show up that way in C# - when it gets sent to SQL the difference becomes more apparent.  Have you tried using `double `in C# instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22768244/1507566 - an explanation of why this occurs and why you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @TabAlleman I was working on converting a old Microsoft access server to a c# application. I decided to just get rid of the float in my class and made it a decimal. Why I had not done this before hand was to keep the entity in line with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the reason for this is that SQL is approximating the value of the floats and doubles. There is no way around this it is a fundamental characteristic of how this data is stored in the database. If it was me in this position I would reassess why I cant change the column.

Your options are thus:

1. Round the data prior to using it in your SELECT statement.
2. Create a separate table joined by the PK and store the precise value
   in there.

I don't like either option to be honest.